# CAML Designer: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

I am new to sharepoint, and this community. I have a CAML Designer program (http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/caml-designer/) that I want to use to run queries on my **Sharepoint Online** lists.

Question:

This designer is supposed to be able to automatically detect sharepoint online sites. But when I click connect I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The website says you have to install the .NET framework 4.5 but when I try to install it, the installation says its already present on my system.

I am using Windows 8, I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed on my machine.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you resolved your problem ? I'm having almost the same probleme with SharePoint 2013 (On-Premise) and Visual Studio 2012. If yes, can you tell me what you did ? Thanks, Wael.

Comment: I did not manage to solve it. :( If you do, please let me know too! Thanks.